# Assigning a line in a text file to a variable in C

Tags: c

I am trying to assign a single line of a text file to a variable in C and this is what I have been using.

```
FILE* filePointer = fopen(fileName, "r");
char output[256];
char actualAnswer1;
fscanf(filePointer, "%s", actualAnswer1);
```

This doesn't work and just returns a null value. What should I do?

Comment: How do you think a "line" can be contained in `char`? You need a `char` array of adequate size.

Comment: @cubo78 how is this different?

Comment: @cubo78 thats the same thing as what i wrote before

Comment: Try `char actualAnswer1[256];` or some other reasonable size. Make sure that `fscanf` cannot read more characters than what fits into the array. To read a line of input I suggest to use `fgets` instead of `fscanf`. (With `fgets` you have to remove the newline yourself.) You should [edit] your question and add enough code to allow compiling and running your program and to reproduce your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "%s" format character of fscanf expects that

> the next pointer must be a pointer to character array that is long
>   enough to hold the input sequence and the terminating null byte
>   ('\0'), which is added automatically. The input string stops at white
>   space or at the maximum field width, whichever occurs first.

This means that instead of `actualAnswer1` which is of type char, you need to provide a character array for example `output`

`fscanf(filePointer, "%s", output);`

The above line can read upto 255 character long string from the file and put a '0' in the 256th spot. If the first string in your file happened to be longer than 255 characters then the program will crash. You can provide a field width specifier to guard against this.

`fscanf(filePointer, "%255s", output);`

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign a string into a char.

Try with this

```
FILE* filePointer = fopen(fileName, "r");
char output[256];
fscanf(filePointer, "%s", output);
```

Take care that your line cannot be grater than 255 characters.